# a href doesn't work. What is going on, i've had others look at it

Tags: html, hyperlink

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="nav.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css">
    <title>Grateful Papers: Home</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!//-- Navbar -- Start -- Navbar -- Start --Navbar -- Start --Navbar -- Start --Navbar -- Start --Navbar -- Start -->
    <table id="top_ta">
      <tr id="top_tr">
        <td id="logo">
        </td>
        <td id="menu">
          <div id="links">
            <h1>
              <a href="about.html">&nbspAbout Us |</a>
              <a href="shop.html">&nbspShop |</a>
              <a href="index.html">&nbspHome&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</a>
              &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
            </h1>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <!//-- Navbar -- End -- Navbar -- Ende -- Navbar -- Ende -- Navbar -- Ende -- Navbar -- Ende -- Navbar -- Ende -- Navbar -->

    <!//-------------------- Body -------------------- Start -------------------- Body -------------------- Start -->
    <div id="content_1">
      <br>
      <div id="content_image_1">
        <a href="shop.html"><img src="./img/product/productt.jpg"></a>
        <img src="./img/product/productg.jpg" ></a>
      <img src="./img/product/productcomingsoon.jpg">
      <img src="./img/product/productcomingsoon.jpg">
      <img src="./img/product/productcomingsoon.jpg">
      <img src="./img/product/productcomingsoon.jpg">
    </div>
    <table id="content_text_1">  
      <tr>
        <td>
          <center>
            <h3>T</h3>
            Our very own line.
          </center>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
  <div id="content_2">
    <br>
    <div id="content_image_2">
      <a href="shop.html"><img src="./img/product/productc.jpg"></a>
      <a href="shop.html"><img src="./img/product/productk.jpg"></a>
      <a href="shop.html"><img src="./img/product/products.jpg"></a>
      <img src="./img/product/productcomingsoon.jpg">
      <img src="./img/product/productcomingsoon.jpg">
      <img src="./img/product/productcomingsoon.jpg">
    </div>
    <table id="content_text_2">  
      <tr>
        <td>
          <center>
            <h3>Brands</h3>
            Other.
          </center>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div id="content_3">
    <br>
    <div id="content_image_3"> 
      <img src="./img/buttons/paypal3.png">
      <img src="./img/buttons/paypallock.png">
      <img src="./img/buttons/paypal2.png">
      <img src="./img/buttons/paypal.png">
    </div>
    <table id="content_text_3">  
      <tr>
        <td>
          <center>
            <h3>About Us</h3>
            happen.
            <br><br>
            We use.  
            <br>&nbsp<br>&nbsp<br>&nbsp<br>
          </center>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>


  <!//-------------------- Body -------------------- Ende -------------------- Body -------------------- Ende -->
  </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to make the code below work.

```
  <a href="shop"><img src="./img/product/productt.jpg"></a>
```

For some reason it doesn't create the link.  I double check all the code.
I've had a few others double check all the code, to make sure i wasn't missing anything.
They say it is fine.
I deleted the file, and saved it again.  I don't know the link isn't work.
Everything else works fine, and the navbar (shop,home,about us) works fine.

Any suggestions?
(also i did uploaded it to the server and doesn't work on there)
Sorry this is so stupid of a question, but if anyone can spot something let me know.  I would be grateful!

Comment: `&nbsp` should be `&nbsp;`

Comment: is `<a href="shop"><img src="./img/product/productt.jpg"></a>` the part that's not working? what do you mean by 'doesn't create the link' is the a tag and image not being shown?

Comment: Do you have a page/redirect setup called "`shop`". In your other links you're pointing to `shop.html`

Comment: Also, not quite sure if those are correct HTML comments, but the regular HTML comment looks like `<!-- my comment -->`.

Comment: Your HTML code creates the <a> links fine, as expected.  All `<a>` links you have written are rendered as you have written them.  The only thing that concerns me is your comments.  I have seen consecutive hyphens `--` break html browser parsing when used inside a comment block but not at the immediate start and end of the block.  Remove all consecutive hyphens from the middle of your comments.

Comment: its doesnt  i already have it as shop.html  the only links that work are the nav links.  There are more links on the page that don't work.

Comment: Yeah every link on the page doesn't work.  I can click the image (image is displayed correctly)  and nothing happens.

Comment: I did fix the html comment.  Still have the problem.  i have never seen this before.  my shop page which uses the same .css and same layout works fine.  I don't understand how only on this page the links don't work.

Comment: Also you know how you can hover on a link and you get the address on the bottom of your web browser.  That doesn't come up.  So there is a problem with the <a href="#">asdfa</a> part.  I tried a basic link, still doesn't work.

Comment: Inspect the elements using your browser's element inspector. Does the link show up where it's supposed to? Is it sized across the whole image? Any other differences you can make out?

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="shop">
```

should be

```
<a href="shop.html">
```

Comment: @deceze ok, but clearly it's *wrong* for OP's case. Logically.

Comment: @deceze Not wrong, but looking at the other links it should probably be `shop.html`.

Answer (score 0):

If the hyperlink that is not working is the first one after the body comment, I can help.

The line reads like this: `<a href="shop">....</a>`

When you click on this link, the webpage will try to find a file called `shop` in the same directory as the webpage. This file it is looking for would have no file extension.

I am assuming the file you are looking for is called `shop.html`, which is in the same directory as the current webpage.

Your code should read: `<a href="shop.html">....</a>`

I hope this helps!

Comment: its doesnt  i already have it as shop.html  the only links that work are the nav links.  There are more links on the page that don't work.

Comment: Try adding a slash before the end of your image tags - `<img src="..." />`